# Maximum likelihood estimation of the log-normal distribution using R

Tags: r

I'm trying to estimate a linear model with a log-normal distributed error term. I already have working code for a linear model with normally distributed errors:

```
library(Ecdat)
library(assertthat)
library(maxLik)

# Load the data
data(Wages1)

# Check what R says
summary(lm(wage ~ school + exper + sex, data = Wages1))


# Use maxLik from package maxLik
# The likelihood function
my_log_lik_pos <- function(theta, data){
    y <- data[, 1]
    x <- data[, -1]
    beta <- head(theta, -1)
    sigma <- tail(theta, 1)
    xb <- x%*%beta
    are_equal(dim(xb), c(nrow(my_data), 1))
    return(sum(log(dnorm(y, mean = xb, sd = sigma))))
}

# Bind the data
my_data <- cbind(Wages1$wage, 1, Wages1$school, Wages1$exper, Wages1$sex)

my_problem <- maxLik(my_log_lik_pos, data = my_data, 
              start = rep(1,5), method = "BFGS")

summary(my_problem)
```

I get approximately the same results. Now I try to do the same, but using the log-normal likelihood. For this, I have to first simulate some data:

```
true_beta <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5)

ys <- my_data[, -1] %*% head(true_beta, -1) + 
      rlnorm(nrow(my_data), 0, tail(true_beta, 1))

my_data_2 <- cbind(ys, my_data[, -1])
```

And the log-likelihood function:

```
my_log_lik_lognorm <- function(theta, data){
    y <- data[, 1]
    x <- data[, -1]
    beta <- head(theta, -1)
    sigma <- tail(theta, 1)
    xb <- x%*%beta
    are_equal(dim(xb), c(nrow(data), 1))
    return(sum(log(dlnorm(y, mean = xb, sd = sigma))))
}

my_problem2 <- maxLik(my_log_lik_lognorm, data = my_data_2, 
               start = rep(0.2,5), method = "BFGS")

summary(my_problem2)
```

The estimated parameters should be around the values of true_beta, but for some reason I find completely different values. I tried with different methods, different starting values but to no avail. I'm sure that I'm missing something obvious, but I don't see what.

Am I right to assume that the log-likelihood of the log-normal distribution is:

```
sum(log(dlnorm(y, mean = .., sd = ...))
```

Unless I'm mistaken, this is the definition of the log-likelihood (sum of the logs of the densities).

Comment: You seem to be asking us to debug your R code. That is off-topic here. If there is a statistical question here, please make it central.

Comment: Well, the code itself runs, there's no bug in it. But I'll amend the question.

Comment: Just because code *runs* doesn't mean it has no bugs. That just means it has no syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue: it seems the problem is not my log-likelihood function. When I try to estimate the model with glm:

```
summary(glm(ys ~ school + exper + sex, family=gaussian(link="log"), data=Wages1))
```

I get the same result as with maxLik and my log-likelihood. It would seem the problem comes from when I tried to simulate some data:

```
ys <- my_data[, -1] %*% head(true_beta, -1) + 
          rlnorm(nrow(my_data), 0, tail(true_beta, 1))
```

The correct way to simulate the data:

```
ys <-  rlnorm(nrow(my_data), my_data[, -1] %*% head(true_beta, -1), tail(true_beta, 1))
```

Now everything works!

Comment: Hi, Bruno! I was curious and visited your website, which I liked a lot (both the theme and the contents). I noticed one of your blog posts ("Using R as a Computer Algebra System with Ryacas") and thought that you might be interested in my yesterday's answer on Cross Validated, containing relevant and additional info: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/140390/31372. I hope that you will like it and/or find it useful. Best regards, Aleksandr.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion (and thanks for the kind words about my site)!